# C# ¿Cómo enviar binarios?

Tags: c#

Amigos, tengo un dilema. Encontré una clase la cual controla un proxy.

Lo que no logro saber es como usarla para enviar paquetes.

La sentencia sería `PortListener.SendToServer(" BINARIO ");`

Este dato me da el proxy como ejemplo de "dato"
Message(3:2:05:01)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace AOPacketListener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExecuteCommand("X-Runner.cmd");
            StartListening();
        }


        private static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            System.Diagnostics.Process process;

            processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();

            // *** Read the streams ***
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            int exitCode = process.ExitCode;

            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error);
            Console.WriteLine("Exit-Code: " + exitCode);


            process.Close();
        }



        public static void StartListening()
        {
            try
            {
                //AllocConsole();
                TcpListener r_Server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 1337);
                r_Server.Start();

                bool isActive = true;

                while (isActive)
                {
                    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    //!
                    //! Wait for the client to connect.
                    //!
                    TcpClient r_Client = r_Server.AcceptTcpClient();

                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                    //!
                    //! Get the stream.
                    //!
                    NetworkStream r_IOStream = r_Client.GetStream();

                    //!
                    //! Keep executing while the client is active.
                    //!
                    while (r_Client.Connected)
                    {
                        using (var r_IOReader = new BinaryReader(r_IOStream))
                        {
                            while (r_IOReader != null)
                            {
                                if (r_IOStream.DataAvailable)
                                {
                                    Byte r_ID = r_IOReader.ReadByte();
                                    UInt16 r_Length = ReverseBytes(r_IOReader.ReadUInt16());
                                    byte[] r_Message = r_IOReader.ReadBytes(r_Length);

                                    Console.WriteLine("Message({0}:{1}:{2})", r_ID, r_Length, BitConverter.ToString(r_Message).Replace("-", ":"));

                                    if (r_ID == 0x03)
                                    Reply(r_IOStream, r_Message, r_Length, r_ID);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //!
                    //! Shutdown and end connection.
                    //!
                    r_Client.Close();
                    isActive = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", exception);
            }
        }

        public static UInt16 ReverseBytes(UInt16 value)
        {
            return (UInt16)((value & 0xFFU) << 8 | (value & 0xFF00U) >> 8);
        }

        public static void SendToClient(NetworkStream pStream, String pMessage)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pMessage))
                Send(pStream, pMessage, true);

        }

        public static void SendToServer(NetworkStream pStream, String pMessage)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pMessage))
                Send(pStream, pMessage, false);
        }

        public static void Send(NetworkStream pStream, String pMessage, bool pForClient)
        {
            int len = (pMessage.Length + 1) * 2;

            Byte[] r_Reply = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0x00, 0x03 + len).ToArray();

            r_Reply[0x00] = pForClient ? (byte)0x01 : (byte)0x02;
            r_Reply[0x01] = (Byte)((len >> 0x08) & 0xFF);
            r_Reply[0x02] = (Byte)(len & 0xFF);

            System.Array.Copy(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pMessage), 0, r_Reply, 0x03, len - 0x02);
            pStream.Write(r_Reply, 0, r_Reply.Length);
            pStream.Flush();
        }


        public static void Reply(NetworkStream pStream, byte[] pData, UInt16 pLength, Byte pID)
        {
            Byte[] r_Reply = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0x00, 0x03 + pLength).ToArray();

            r_Reply[0x00] = pID;
            r_Reply[0x01] = (Byte)((pLength >> 0x08) & 0xFF);
            r_Reply[0x02] = (Byte)(pLength & 0xFF);

            System.Array.Copy(pData, 0, r_Reply, 0x03, pLength);
            pStream.Write(r_Reply, 0, r_Reply.Length);
            pStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pero en el código el parametro de SendToServer() es un string, no un binario.
Lo usarias

```
string mensaje = "mensaje como string";
PortListener.SendToServer(mensaje);
```

Si quieres enviar un binario deberias encodearlo a base64 para poder envialro como string

[Convert.ToBase64String Method (Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Si tienes un archivo podrias usar el `File.ReadAllByte()` y esto le aplicar con convert a base64 para poder enviarlo como mensaje.
Por supuesto del otro lado debes aplicar el paso inverso, tomas el string en base64 y obtienes con

[Convert.FromBase64String Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)

el array de byte para grabarlo con `File.WriteAllBytes()`

---

**>>en el caso de que yo deba si o si enviar binario cómo sería?**

En el metodo actual estas tomando el mensaje como string y el aplicas un encode con Unicode, para luego convertir este a un array de byte por medio de Array.Copy()

Quizas solo debes cambiar la sobrecarga del metodo

```
    public static void Send(NetworkStream pStream, byte[] pMessage)
    {
        pStream.Write(pMessage, 0, pMessage.Length);
        pStream.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Leandro una consulta, en el caso de que yo deba si o si enviar binario cómo sería? 

Es decir esta app es un proxy y me devuelve paquetes que me los convierte a HEX, este es un ejemplo de paquete Message(3:2:1C:06) donde el primer numero le pertenece al proxy y el restante seria el paquete que lo veo en HEX.